# Java object construction by factory method: attribute vs constructor (via method)

Tags: java, constructor, factory

I have a class (A) that uses (1) another class (B) by factory method (2):

```
(A)
public class MazeGame{
  private Room room;  // (1)

  public MazeGame() {
    this.room= makeRoom();   // (2)
  }

  protected Room makeRoom() {
    return new OrdinaryRoom();
  }
}
```

for example:

```
(B)
public class OrdinaryRoom{
  private String name = "ordinaryRoom";
}
```

I can also write (A) as:

```
(A2)
public class MazeGame{
  private Room room = makeRoom();  // (1)(2)

  protected Room makeRoom(){
    return new OrdinaryRoom();
  }
}
```

What's the difference between (A) and (A2)?
there's some advantage by using one instead the other?

Comment: There is no difference, other than that the first option is unnecessarily long.

Comment: the answer is no. They are identical

Comment: no real differences. Note that your factory doesn't need to be protected, should be located in the room class and should be static as it doesn't require a MazeGame instance to return a room.

Comment: There is no difference.

Comment: Tank to all of you you for clarification. for @davidxxx : I made makeRoom() protected because I wanted only new Mazegame() could do it. and it's not static for same reason: only crerating Mazegame can "invokes" making a room. (is it wrong?)

Comment: With (A) you could have several constructors which initialize the `room` in different ways.
I would also prefer (A) so that all the fields are initialized in one way only (in the constructor).

Comment: @Marco you are welcome. But it will not be the case as OrdinaryRoom is public and so any classes may instantiate it.

Comment: Good @davidxxx. I unterstood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The differences I see:

- A tiny difference in the **moment of initializing** `room`: With (A), it's initialized after finishing the super constructor `Object()` call, inside the `MazeGame()` constructor. With (A2) the initializing takes place after finishing the super constructor `Object()` call and before the first line of any `MazeGame(...)` constructor. In your case, it doesn't make a difference.
- The initialization from (A2) applies to **all constructors** that `MazeGame` will ever have, while the (A) approach only initializes `room` **in this single `MazeGame()` constructor**, not affecting any constructors you might add in the future.
- Moving the initialization to the `room` field "allowed" you to remove the constructor from your source code and to **rely on the default constructor** that the compiler generates in case there is no constructor. I don't see that as a benefit, but as a maintenance risk, because if in the future you want to add some e.g. `MazeGame(Room room)` constructor, this not only adds the new constructor (the expected result), but also removes the default one - might be quite unexpected.

Comment: Tank you for your deeper analysis (to @lexycore too). I think also (A2) it's a better solution because: it's possible to change constructors without depending of first line condition and also because it's better to declare all operation of an object construction inside constructor itself to make it usable by everyone (maintenance of code)